# Create database Table by user input value in php

Tags: php, jquery, sql, database, sqlsrv

Form  to send the name for the table to create

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cdbt').click(function (e) {  
 e.preventDefault();
    $.post("insert.php", 
    { input_value : $("#myInput").val()},
     function(data) {
       $('#response').html(data);
      console.log("Success");
    });
  });
});
</script> 
 <form action=""  id= "cdbt" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
```

**insert.php**

```
$value = $_POST['input_value'];     
$sql1 = "CREATE TABLE $value";
```

**Create database Table by user input value in php**

Comment: Ouch, this sounds like a really bad idea. SQL injection, and creating tables on the fly doesn't sound like a good approach. Why do you need this?

Comment: What is your SQL server / database engine (based on `sqlsrv` tag you are probably using SQL Server and PHP Driver for SQL Server)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach submit event on form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cdbt').submit(function (e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("insert.php", 
    { input_value : $("#myInput").val()},
     function(data) {
       $('#response').html(data);
      console.log("Success");
    });
  });
});
```

Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) you should [escape](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) values like:

```
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['input_value'])
```